# angular material checkbox: prevent ripple when link in label is checked

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular (10) Material checkbox with a link in the label that has a click handler to open a dialog with reference info:

```
 <mat-checkbox formControlName="certification">
          By checking this box, I certify that all shipment information provided is correct and I agree to adhere to the
          <span class="fake-link" (click)="openUspsPrivacyAgreement($event)"> USPS Privacy Act Statement </span> and all
          other country-specific requirements.
        </mat-checkbox>
```

My click handler is

```
  openUspsPrivacyAgreement(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.dialogService.open(DialogUspsPrivacyAgreementComponent);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

It works in that the dialog opens and the checkbox is not selected, which is what I want.

However, the ripple fires on the checkbox anyway.  Is there a way to prevent the ripple when I click on my text but have it work when the checkbox is clicked?

I thought what I did was enough, as it does prevent the click from getting to the checkbox and checking it.

Comment: Did you try just to do `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();
` before opening dialog?

Comment: It might be easiest to just set [disableRipple]="true" for mat-checkbox. You'll lose the ripple on the normal check, but seems a small price to pay to avoid something more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `mat-checkbox` ignores internal element `stopPropagation`. So, you could create an workaround where you add dynamic variable `isRippleDisabled` as boolean flag to your checkbox

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="certification" [disableRipple]="isRippleDisabled">
```

and switch it off (true) when modal open, and back to normal, when modal close (false).

```
  openUspsPrivacyAgreement(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.isRippleDisabled = true; // set to false when dialog close
    this.dialogService.open(DialogUspsPrivacyAgreementComponent);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<mat-checkbox>Checked 1</mat-checkbox>
```

to the app.component in the source code and it still has 'hover' effect, it could be  disabled it through CSS.

The fix would be:

```
.mat-ripple { display: none; }
```

or `.mat-checkbox-ripple` only for checkbox